# Loopback 3 - Delete or edit nested models involving a mapping table

Tags: mysql, database, loopbackjs, loopback

**Question: Is there a loopback way of handling updates if I store selected values in of mapping table? Else is there a proper argument (apart from this will make your life easier) in support of second approach of storing the cities as an array of ids.**

**Context**
I have a `loopback 3` api server with `MySQL` datasource. To store multi select values, I am using a mapping table. For example, a person has many cities. So there is PersonCity table which has a `person_id` and a `city_id`. And I have a hasMany relation that looks like this:

```
"cities": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "PersonCity",
      "foreignKey": "person_id",
      "options": {
        "nestRemoting": true
      }
    }
```

From my UI application, the requirement is to have a multi select dropdown with all cities and a person can choose many cities. I can get the cities of a person by calling an api like `persons/{id}/cities` which brings me all cities from the `PersonCity` table where `person_id` is the `id` mentioned in api call.

The response I get is like this:

```
[{
  id: 14,
  person_id: 1,
  city_id: 1
},
{
  id: 19,
  person_id: 1,
  city_id: 2
},
{
  id: 34,
  person_id: 1,
  city_id: 3
},{
  id: 34,
  person_id: 1,
  city_id: 4
}]
```

and then I can extract all `city_id` to get the selected cities for my multi select dropdown`s value.

The problem comes in editing. Let's say I want to remove one of the selected cities and add two more.

One approach would be to delete the city by a `delete` api call like this `/persons/1/cities/{id}` and then do post calls for the new cities. And the UI code needs to take care of this. In this case, UI needs to have information on the previous cities, determine the ones to delete and ones to add.

Another approach that makes life much easier is to forget the relations and mapping table, just store the cities in an array of `city_id` inside `person` and then update the person with new array. Array is what my select box is going to consume and it feels natural.

I am not a DB expert, but going by the rules of DB design, I ended up with a mapping table to store this data and life is very difficult for the UI side.

Comment: Another approach would be to delete all of the rows for a specific user id and where the city is not in the list of selected cities, then use an insert on duplicate key update statement to insert/update the list of new rows.

Comment: Yes, that would be an efficient way, still UI would need to take care of that, or I need to create a remote method to handle this.

Comment: Do you consider to add `before save`? So when you save your person (if it's on the person form and you're saving it anyway) you could update the cities that the user owns inside the hook. That would require some custom code but would be clean I guess.

Comment: The UI shouldn't be updating the DB. That should be done on the back end in some language on the server such as PHP.

Comment: Yes, it feels anti-pattern for the UI to care about DB implementation. That's why I am looking for a loopback specific pattern how it can be taken care of, possibly without custom code using juggler.